# Is there any way to get the default domain of Client() in unittest of Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-unittest

I would like to get the default domain name of `Client()` in Django unittests. I saw a way to change the default one. But didn't find a way to get the default domain name.

Comment: Assuming you have an instance of `Client()` called `client`, does `client.environ['SERVER_NAME']` contain what you want?

Comment: I think **Client()** doesn't have `environ` attribute

Comment: Do you _think_ so, or did you test?

Comment: Yes. I just tired. I tried running my test now,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default domain name for Django's test client is `testserver`. It's [hardcoded](https://github.com/django/django/blob/16411b8400ad08f90c236bb2e18f65c655f903f8/django/test/client.py#L254) in the `RequestFactory` base class.

If you want to change the domain for the specific request, you can just pass it as the kwarg:

```
self.client.get('/some-path', SERVER_NAME="anotherdomain.com")
```

Comment: Ah, I get it. Anyway, please consider marking this answer as accepted, as it answers the exact question you've asked: the default domain of Django's test `Client()`. Or rephrase your initial question so that your own answer gets in line with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase

The default test URL will be **http://localhost:8082** and we can request to the same while running tests. And its working for me.

Comment: Sure, but your question was about the domain name in the `Client` class, not about the bind port of the `LiveServerTestCase`. That's a completely different thing.

Comment: Yes you are right . Actually I needed to run the test locally and send requests manually to the urls. LiveServerTestCase returns me the uri by self.live_server_url

Answer (score 0):

is this the (pytest) answer you are looking for?

```
@pytest.fixture()
def client() -> "django.test.client.Client":
    """like the default pytest client with a new domain name."""
    skip_if_no_django()
    return Client(SERVER_NAME = 'my-server.com')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).